# SQL Error [512] [21000]: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does it not work? (SQL Server)

```
UPDATE
    someTable
SET
    name='AB'
WHERE 
    id IN (
        SELECT t.id 
        FROM someTable t 
        WHERE t.name='ABC'
        )
```

this one doesn't work too

```
UPDATE
    someTable
SET
    name='AB'
WHERE 
    name='ABC'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you must have a broken `UPDATE` trigger on the table.

A common error in triggers is not taking into account that a statement can affect multiple or zero rows and thus that the `INSERTED`/`DELETED` tables don't always contain exactly one row.

Look in the trigger for constructs like

```
SET @ID = (select ID FROM INSERTED)
```

Comment: problem solved! there is an update-trigger on the table!! thank you very much!